# Wrapping c++ class to use it in Lua using SWIG - need simple example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lua, swig

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to using both SWIG and lua, and a mediocre C++ developer, and I just don't seem to understand how I can bind C++ classes with Lua.

My end goal is to have an instance of a class, pass it to my lua script which manipulates that object in a certain way, then I retrieve that object in c++ and do whatever else I want to do with it.

So... I've downloaded Lua and C++, compiled a few examples, I am able to run some lua script in my c++ program. So far so good.

Now, I've downloaded SWIG. I'm using VC2010 on Windows 7. From what I understand I'm suppose to create an interface file. So I've created one, example.i:

```
%module creature
class Creature
{
public:
    Creature(void);
    Creature(int id);
    ~Creature(void);

(...) the rest of my class here
```

(Just added %module creature to my Creature.h and saved it as creature.i). I ran SWIG using

```
 swig -c++ -lua creature.i
```

and got my creature.cxx file.

Now, I'll probably embarrass myself now but... I don't know what to do next. Am I suppose to build the output file somehow? How can I use it now? I've read here http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Lua.html that I need to link the generated file (*.cxx) with the rest of my code (so I do that by simply including the file in my project and adding the line #include "Creature.h"). But when I compile I get errors like

```
error C2065: 'LUA_GLOBALSINDEX' : undeclared identifier
error C2036: 'const luaL_reg *' : unknown size
```

I have also tried compiling it using MinGW but I get the same problem. It would be great if someone could show me an example or a step-by-step tutorial of how I can use these tools together, as I have a hard time grasping the whole idea. This is definitely due to my lack of understanding of the basics of how this should be used so please be gentle to a noob.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Searching for the missing identifier in the Lua distribution tells me it's been removed in version 5.2 - it's possible SWIG wasn't updated to work with it yet. Try downgrading your Lua to 5.1.

Comment: Considering the reception to Lua 5.2, many would consider using it an *up*-grade, not a down-grade.

Comment: It compiles but now I get a linker error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_error referenced in function __wrap_new_Creature. But even after I manage to compile it, how can I use it afterwards?

Comment: @NicolBolas I haven't been keeping up with Lua development news. Is Lua 5.2 ill-received? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: Just to let you know guys, it has indeed been a problem with 5.2 and after downgrading to 5.1 I compile without any issues. I still need to learn how to use these tools but I'll probably manage somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWIG is a tool for linking scripting languages to C or C++ code. It works as a *preprocess* step: you run the SWIG executable on a .swig file, which produces a bit of C or C++ code. You then build that code into whatever project you want to do the linking to that scripting language for.

SWIG's Lua support is most certainly not compatible with Lua 5.2. Indeed, you will find very little code out there that is compatible with Lua 5.2. If you want to actually do something with Lua code, stick with 5.1 at least for the time being.

Comment: So if I manage to compile that c++ file that I've included in my object, is it enough that I include it (using #include) in on of my classes where I use lua and call luaopen_creature(L);? Or is there a different way of building these wrappers? Apologies, I'm new to this.

Comment: Normally, SWIG is used to create Lua DLLs, which are opened with the `require` Lua function. If you're trying to use a static SWIG module, then you'll have to build the SWIG source file with `STATIC_LINKED` #define. To initialize it for a Lua state, you need to run the `luaopen_*` function, where `*` is the name of your SWIG module. SWIG's documentation explains much of this, so go have a look.

Comment: Just recently a patch to add Lua 5.2 support (it's very simple, just a few tweaks) was added to the SWIG dev sources, so it should be OK in the next version.

Comment: I'll accept your answer Nicol although you haven't really explained anything that I didn't know except for the problems with 5.2, for which I'm grateful.

Answer (score 1):

> My end goal is to have an instance of a class, pass it to my lua
>   script which manipulates that object in a certain way, then I retrieve
>   that object in c++ and do whatever else I want to do with it.

I may be mistaken, but you don't 'pass' an instance of C++ classes to Lua, what you really do is create C++ bindings to Lua whereby you're actually instantiating a C++ class in the Lua script itself.

i.e Say you have a C++ class called Foo with a single method called add(x, y). You can then instantiate and use that class in Lua by doing something like (assuming you've used Swig to create the wrapper file).

```
foo_instance = Foo()
foo_instance:add(4, 3)
```

I was having some misadventures when using Swig and Lua with my C++ program so I wrote a tutorial (so that I don't forget how I did it). You can view it here... http://glennmccord.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/binding-c-to-lua-using-swig/

Hopefully it can get you started.